# searchRecord isn't rendering correct info or takes several times to display

Tags: google-sheets, search, data-entry

I'm running a Apps Script to create a data entry form.  Sometimes my searchRecord function works if I run it several times.  Sometimes it doesn't pull any info, but never gives me the warning screen, sometimes it pulls the info from the last search.  I'm not sure where the problem is.  I have copied the code below.

```html
//Function to Search the record

function searchRecord(){
  
  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active Google Sheet
  
  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form"); //declare a variable and set with the User Form reference
  
  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Existing Customers"); //declare variable and set the reference of database sheet

  var str=shUserForm.getRange("B2").getValue();  //get data input for search button
  
  var values=datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from the used range and assigning it to values variable

  var valuesFound=false; //variable to store boolean value
  
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
  {
      var rowValue=values[i]; //declare a variable and storing the value

      //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
      if(rowValue[6]==str){
        
        shUserForm.getRange("B12").setValue(rowValue[0]);        
        shUserForm.getRange("B15").setValue(rowValue[1]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B23").setValue(rowValue[2]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B17").setValue(rowValue[3]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E17").setValue(rowValue[4]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B8").setValue(rowValue[6]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E8").setValue(rowValue[7]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B19").setValue(rowValue[8]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E19").setValue(rowValue[9]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B21").setValue(rowValue[10]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E21").setValue(rowValue[11]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E23").setValue(rowValue[12]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E12").setValue(rowValue[13]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B25").setValue(rowValue[14]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E25").setValue(rowValue[15]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B27").setValue(rowValue[16]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E27").setValue(rowValue[17]);        
        shUserForm.getRange("B29").setValue(rowValue[18]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E29").setValue(rowValue[19]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B31").setValue(rowValue[20]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E10").setValue(rowValue[21]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B33").setValue(rowValue[22]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B35").setValue(rowValue[23]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B37").setValue(rowValue[24]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E31").setValue(rowValue[25]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E35").setValue(rowValue[26]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B39").setValue(rowValue[27]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E39").setValue(rowValue[27]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B41").setValue(rowValue[29]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E15").setValue(rowValue[30]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B43").setValue(rowValue[31]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E43").setValue(rowValue[32]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B45").setValue(rowValue[33]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E45").setValue(rowValue[34]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B47").setValue(rowValue[35]);
        shUserForm.getRange("B49").setValue(rowValue[36]);  
        shUserForm.getRange("B10").setValue(rowValue[37]);
        shUserForm.getRange("E37").setValue(rowValue[5]);      
       valuesFound=true;
        return;//come out from the loop

      }


  
 if(valuesFound=false){
//to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the alert function
var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getui();
ui.alert("No Record Found");}

  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

There are different points in your code that could be improved, I attach the updated function correcting the basics:

- **Indentation**: This is easy to fix, just press `ctrl + shft + i` to correctly indent the code.
- **Break statement**: Use the word `break` to [break a loop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_break.asp).
- **Wrong comparison operator**: The second `if` has only one `=` instead of two `==`. Check [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)
- **Structural logic**: Inside the for loop there are two ifs. Only the second one depends on the value of the `valuesFound` variable, which when modified breaks the loop, so it is not really doing anything.
- **Readability**: It is difficult to understand what the code is doing and so many `setValue` boxes with no apparent connection is confusing.

In addition, it is difficult to offer help if the behavior of the function is variable and the reason is not known. Apparently, it should always give the same result.

### Updated code

```js
function searchRecord() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active Google Sheet
  var shUserForm = ss.getSheetByName("User Form"); //declare a variable and set with the User Form reference
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Existing Customers"); //declare variable and set the reference of database sheet
  var str = shUserForm.getRange("B2").getValue();  //get data input for search button
  var values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from the used range and assigning it to values variable
  var valuesFound = false; //variable to store boolean value
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getui();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var rowValue = values[i]; //declare a variable and storing the value

    //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
    if (rowValue[6] == str) {
      shUserForm.getRange("B12").setValue(rowValue[0]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B15").setValue(rowValue[1]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B23").setValue(rowValue[2]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B17").setValue(rowValue[3]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E17").setValue(rowValue[4]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B8").setValue(rowValue[6]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E8").setValue(rowValue[7]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B19").setValue(rowValue[8]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E19").setValue(rowValue[9]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B21").setValue(rowValue[10]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E21").setValue(rowValue[11]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E23").setValue(rowValue[12]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E12").setValue(rowValue[13]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B25").setValue(rowValue[14]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E25").setValue(rowValue[15]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B27").setValue(rowValue[16]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E27").setValue(rowValue[17]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B29").setValue(rowValue[18]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E29").setValue(rowValue[19]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B31").setValue(rowValue[20]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E10").setValue(rowValue[21]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B33").setValue(rowValue[22]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B35").setValue(rowValue[23]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B37").setValue(rowValue[24]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E31").setValue(rowValue[25]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E35").setValue(rowValue[26]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B39").setValue(rowValue[27]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E39").setValue(rowValue[27]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B41").setValue(rowValue[29]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E15").setValue(rowValue[30]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B43").setValue(rowValue[31]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E43").setValue(rowValue[32]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B45").setValue(rowValue[33]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E45").setValue(rowValue[34]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B47").setValue(rowValue[35]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B49").setValue(rowValue[36]);
      shUserForm.getRange("B10").setValue(rowValue[37]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E37").setValue(rowValue[5]);
      valuesFound = true;
      break
    }

    if (valuesFound == false) {
      //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the alert function
      ui.alert("No Record Found");
    }

  }
}
```